# Unable to shim WebException with Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimNotSupportedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, microsoft-fakes

I am attempting to test some code outside of my control that checks for a `WebException` and reacts appropriately.  I am trying to generate a shim for `WebException`, but keep receiving a

> Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimNotSupportedException.

Here is the source of the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Search_WebException404Ignored()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        mockApiSettings
            .Setup(p => p.ListApiUrl)
            .Returns("http://fakeUrl/?value={0}{1}");

        var exception = new ShimWebException
        {
            ResponseGet = () => new ShimHttpWebResponse {StatusCodeGet = () => HttpStatusCode.NotFound},
        };

        mockServiceProxy
            .Setup(m => m.CallServiceAsync(It.IsAny<Uri>(), RequestMethodType.GET, null))
            .ThrowsAsync(exception);

        var items = await service.Search("ListName_0", new[] {"ListValue_0", "ListValue_0"});
    }
}
```

I have updated the System.fakes file as so:

```xml
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
  <Assembly Name="System" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.WebRequest!"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.HttpWebRequest!"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.HttpWebResponse!"/>
    <Add FullName="System.Net.WebException!"/>
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

Doesn't seem to help.  Could it be because I'm also using MOQ?

The test project does not use a `.testSettings` file as mentioned in other posts. Using 64 bit for source and unit tests.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes 12.0.0.0.  No warnings show in the output for shim generation for those items.

Comment: Why do you have the `!` in the `FullName`? Haven't see that before in the fakes file.

Comment: Honestly, I have not been able to find a reference mentioning that.  All examples I found when Googling it showed the exclamation point there, so I just sheep'd it.  Tried removing them, didn't make a difference.

Comment: Adding ! to the end of the filter will make it a precise case-sensitive match. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error when my unit test project is referencing `Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes` **12.0** and running some tests with `Shims` within VS2015.

I managed to fix the issue by updating that DLL file to the one from VS2015 Public Assemblies folder, in my case it is `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.dll`.

I didn't have to regenerate my System.4.0.0.0.Fakes reference after updating the DLL file, and I have exactly the same System.fakes file as you including the `!` in the `FullName`.

**Note:** It's also a good idea to check the version of your `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`, and update it to version **14.0** as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try it out ASAP.